# Entity Framework 6 adds "set" at the end of every entity

Tags: entity-framework

After creating a database model with Entity Framework 6 that looks like this (I am aware that .NET Core is out):

[image]

EF generates this code:

```
public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Statevalues> Statevalues { get; set; }
```

in the model context but also creates tables in the database that are called:

```
StatevaluesSet  
UserSet
```

Why is it using `Set` at the end of each name?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it with EntityFramework by Microsoft version 6.2.0. with a simple DbContext with Schools and Students, and I only got a table named `Schools` and a table named `Students`.

To override standard table naming, override DbContext.OnModelCreating.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     // give table Schools a special name:
     modelBuilder.Entity<School>()
         .HasEntitySetName("MySpecialSchools");
}
```